# Omitting parameters in primitive recursive functions

Tags: recursion

will replacing the usual schema of primitive recursion:
$$ 
f(0,\vec x) = c (\vec x)\\
f(n+1,\vec x) = g(f(n,\vec x), n, \vec x)
$$
by the form:
$$
f(0,\vec x) = c(\vec x)\\
f(n+1,\vec x) = g(f(n,\vec x)) 
$$

lead to the same class of primitive recursive functions?

Comment: If you can define products absolutely, otherwise maybe not..

Comment: This looks like an exercise in computability theory. If not please explain why are you interested in this question. Please also check our [help/on-topic] for description of the scope of this site and suggestions for other sites in case your question is off-topic here.

Comment: It is not an exercise. As a side project I am implementing a small functional language for embedded systems (with some verification/security feats). While thinking about the core langage this question arose..

Comment: Yes, if your set of initial functions is rich enough that you can implement ordered pairs (including the projection functions).

Comment: I use the usual formulation (as given eg. in Wikipedia). So I have (the usual) projection functions but no pairing. I don't see how I could implement pairing without multiplication and I cannot define multiplication.